# (Python) A program I'm supposed to improve upon runs on one machine but not on another (both use ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8, pipenv

From the error messages I assume the second machine is just missing a certain package or something, but the most obvious suspect "httplib" is already installed. And the message itself is a bit much, I have trouble not getting lost in the sheer volume. Does something catch the eye of anyone of you? Someone more experienced?

````
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./MetagenApp.py", line 38, in <module>
    metagen_net = start_network(dockerclient)
  File "/home/boxursa/Desktop/metagenapp-master/MetagenApp/network.py", line 15, in start_network
    metagen_net = client.networks.create("metagen_net",
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/networks.py", line 156, in create
    resp = self.client.api.create_network(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/network.py", line 152, in create_network
    res = self._post_json(url, data=data)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 289, in _post_json
    return self._post(url, data=json.dumps(data2), **kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _post
    return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boxursa/.local/share/virtualenvs/metagenapp-master-cR0L49Yy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))```
````

Comment: A backtrace on its own isn't usually enough to diagnose a problem.  Can you edit the question and include a [mcve], with enough code to demonstrate what's going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I got handed a full program with like 20 skripts all importing each other, it's beyond me to reduce it to a minimal example. I was hoping you'd recognize the names of the protocols or packages or whatever, that I'm missing. As I said. the same code runs smoothly on another machine. It must be missing some certain software that solves all the error messages at once.

Answer (score 0):

The program tries to conect to a Unix socket, but the file does not exist.

Why not? another program should be already running and listening on the other side of the Unix socket.

Comment: Can't have anything to do with me using a virtualmachine (oracle vm virtualbox) for this, can it?